# Computing $\operatorname{inf}_{x>0}\; e^{-xt}(1-2a^2x)^{-1/2}$, for $t>0$ and $a>0$

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

> We are given $t>0$ and $a>0$. Compute
> $$\operatorname{inf}_{x>0}\; e^{-xt}(1-2a^2x)^{-1/2}$$

So if I compute even the minimum by considering the derivatives, we see that this is obtained for $x=\frac{t-a^2}{2a^2t}$, and therefore the infimum is given by $\frac{\sqrt t}{a^2} \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{t}{2a^2}\right)$.

But what do I do if $t<a^2?$

Comment: How can you be sure that the local minimum is a global infimum?

Comment: If $t>a^2$ there is just one time where the derivative equals $0$, so in this case I have only one minimum.

Comment: That tells you about *local* minima, not global infima. Consider the function $1/\cosh(x) - 0.5/\cosh(2x)$ which has a local minimum at $x=0$, but the infimum of the function is $0$, realised 'at infinity'.

Comment: I take it we're only to consider $0 < x < 1/(2a^2)$.

Comment: The expression is undefined at $x=1/(2a^2)$, and purely imaginary if $x>1/(2a^2)$. So you should have written $\inf_{0\le x<1/(2a^2)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  The domain of the function  is $(0,\frac  1{2a^{2}})$.  If $f'(x)$ vanishes at only one point in the real line and you are excluding that point from the domain (as in this case when $t <a^{2}$) then $f'$ is always positive or always negative and $f$ is montonic in its domain. The infimum of such a function is the least of the values or the limiting values at the end points. Hence you only have to find $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to c-} f(x)$ where $c=\frac 1 {2a^{2}}$. The smaller of these two numbers is the infimum  of $f$.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. So, we have $\operatorname{lim}_{x \rightarrow 0_+} f(x)=1$ and $\operatorname{lim}_{x \rightarrow c_-} f(x)=\infty$. So do I have that the infimum is $\frac{sqrt t}{a^2} e^{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{t}{2a^2}}$ if $t>a^2$ and $1$ else?

Comment: @samabu Right. The infimum is therefore $1$ when $t<a^{2}$